# How to make JSON Array using square bracket

Tags: arrays, json, reactjs

have a nice day everyone, i want to ask something, i need to make JSON array using square bracket instead of curly breacket, but now i've JSON like this:

```
{
noTransaksi: "202006041323372",
nopolTransaksi: "B11",
nominalTransaksi: "1.000",
masukTransaksi: "04 June 2020 13:23:37",
keluarTransaksi: "04 June 2020 14:26:25",
lokasiTransaksi: "Jakarta",
nipKaryawan: "002002",
shiftTransaksi: "1"
},
{
noTransaksi: "202006040703302",
nopolTransaksi: "B2213",
nominalTransaksi: "0",
masukTransaksi: "04 June 2020 07:03:30",
keluarTransaksi: "04 June 2020 14:25:42",
lokasiTransaksi: "Jakarta",
nipKaryawan: "002007",
shiftTransaksi: "1"
},//...
```

i want to change it to something like this:

```
[
noTransaksi: "202006041323372",
nopolTransaksi: "3752",
nominalTransaksi: "1.000",
masukTransaksi: "04 June 2020 13:23:37",
keluarTransaksi: "04 June 2020 14:26:25",
lokasiTransaksi: "RSUDTA",
nipKaryawan: "002002",
shiftTransaksi: "1"
],
[
noTransaksi: "202006040703302",
nopolTransaksi: "AG1592",
nominalTransaksi: "0",
masukTransaksi: "04 June 2020 07:03:30",
keluarTransaksi: "04 June 2020 14:25:42",
lokasiTransaksi: "RSUDTA",
nipKaryawan: "002007",
shiftTransaksi: "1"
],//....
```

so i can fit the JSON to my datatable, because it need square bracket instead of curly bracket, anyway i'm using reactjs too, it is possible to make JSON array like that?

oh ya, this is my code

```
if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){  
                     $emparray = array();
                         if(mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0){
                         while ($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {


                                $emparray[] = array(

                                'noTransaksi'=>$row['noTransaksi'],
                                'nopolTransaksi'=>strtoupper($row['nopolTransaksi']),

                                'nominalTransaksi'=>number_format($row['nominalTransaksi'],0,",","."),
                                'masukTransaksi'=>date("d F Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['masukTransaksi'])),
                                'keluarTransaksi'=>date("d F Y H:i:s", strtotime($row['keluarTransaksi'])),


                                'lokasiTransaksi'=>strtoupper($row['lokasiTransaksi']),
                                'nipKaryawan'=>strtoupper($row['nipKaryawan']),
                                'shiftTransaksi'=>$row['shiftTransaksi'],
                                        );
                                    }

                                    $no++;
                                   }

               echo json_encode($emparray);
            }
            mysqli_close($con);
```

i really appriciate if somebody can help me:)

Answer (score 0):

The square brackets produce a list/array.

The curly brackets produce an object with key/value pairs.

The list can then be a value of a key/value pair.

you cant just change it u can use [] inside the {} brackets

Comment: Thanks very much for your answer, so there's now way i can change it ya?